# What Else do I Need to Make a Speaker Work in These Conditions?

Tags: speakers, computer-architecture

Recently, I was faced with a slight challenge.

My computer stopped wanting to power on, and I needed it to work fast. As a computer technician (in-home), I had all of the tools necessary to fix the problem. Though, I somehow lost my extra motherboard speaker over time. So I got to work on constructing one.

I grabbed some of my microcontroller jumper cables for making the speaker and a female to female 4 wire cable to put on the motherboard header.

So far, I have an old speaker with the ground wires twisted together, and the left and right speaker wires twisted together.

Along with that, I have two jumper wires with one end on each stripped off (to connect with speaker and plug into female cable).

Going back to my question, *what will I need to make this work*?

I'm not very familiar with how to make electrical circuits, so I cannot go on without some help. I have some labeled resistors around, so if necessary, I have those.

Answer (score 1):

The "motherboard speaker" in PCs has usually been just a bare dynamic speaker. As such there is no need to create a circuit for it, just connect the two speaker wires directly to the appropriate connector on the motherboard.

Certainly one *could* create an amplifier circuit for it if one wanted, but the sparse use the speaker gets along with the requirement to power the amplifier itself makes such an endeavor essentially pointless.

Comment: So no damage would be caused to the motherboard itself?

Comment: no, there would be no damage. PC Speakers really are nothing but a magnet, a coil in front of that magnet, and a bit of wire to connect to your motherboard.

Comment: Well, unless the PC speaker has a higher rated impedance than the replacement speaker. Then you could fry the board.

Comment: Sticking with a 8ohm, 1-1.5W speaker should be just fine though.